# Experian credit report: what are major credit cards?

Tags: credit-card, credit-report

My Experian credit report says that one of the factors negatively contributing to my credit score is the lack of "major credit cards currently open." The report further explains this in the following way: "Your report does not show any open, currently active major credit card accounts, such as Discover, American Express, VISA, or MasterCard." Wait a second, I do have VISA credit card with the Bank of America. What is the point here?

Comment: Does it appear on the report? Is it indeed a credit card, or a debit?

Comment: Yes, it is a credit card and it does appear on the report.

Comment: Then I'd say to give Experian a call and ask them what it is they expect BoA to report, and then call BoA and ask them to report it.

Comment: Leo: Was this resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, that card issuer isn't reporting the card or reporting it correctly. Yes, a BOA Visa is a major credit card.

Comment: Shall I consult with BOA or with Experian about this issue?

Comment: Good question. Experian, and the other agencies only wish to hear from you if there's an error. Omissions are a different story. A card issuer has no obligation to report anything, only to report correctly. I'd contact BOA and ask why they are not reporting your account.